# setting hostname dynamically for oracle jodbc connection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, hostname

I have an app that uses the Oracle DB. The app is also stored in Git on the following branches: development, consolidation, test and production.

There are also 4 different databases. One is used for development, another for testing, etc.

The connection information (defined for Hibernate) is as follows:

**from the application.properties file**

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@mylocalhost\:1527\:DSV
spring.datasource.username=myapps
spring.datasource.password=testing
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

What I need to do is to make sure that "mylocalhost" gets changed to a different hostname depending upon the branch the code is on:

```
Example:

Development -> spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@DBDevelopment\:1527\:DSV

Testing -> spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@DBTesting\:1527\:DSV

etc.
```

I am using Eclipse IDE. Jenkins is being used to build the .jar executable file. Again, Git is being used to store the code (with the 4 branches).

How can I define the application.properties file so that the hostname can be changed dynamically?

Comment: Is it a maven project ? If yes, then you can use [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and use diffetent config filed for each project.

Comment: Configuration files are static.  Have different configuration files for each setting.  Rework your application to bundle the appropriate configuration file for each destination instead of relying on branch names.  You might even consider not bundling the configuration with the code.

Comment: @krokodilko - thanks for the input.Found this online as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3gEgh44iQQ and am looking into using it

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - currently using application.properties file under Maven. Above you wrote "You might even consider not bundling the configuration with the code". How do you get Maven to refer to an application.properties file that sits outside of the project? TIA

Comment: @CaseyHarrils Depending on your needs you may want to not bake in your configuration files with your application but instead provide the configuration map at runtime (when the application runs).   This separates code and configuration which is typically a good idea.  Are you currently asking Maven to alter source before building or are you reading application.properties in your own code at runtime?